# JSON from Tracker Network API (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

I am having problems reading data from my API. I can see all of the data that is in my API in Xcode.

Here is the data that I am trying to Parse.

```
  "data": {
    "id": "2f464c52-81a5-4b2d-9d08-21baf10134bd",
    "type": "player",
    "metadata": {
      "statsCategoryOrder": [
        "levels",
        "combat",
        "game",
        "bullets",
        "ekia-enemy-killed-in-action",
        "objective",
        "team-play",
        "extra"
      ],
      "platformId": 1,
      "platformUserHandle": "BarMexico67",
      "accountId": "2f464c52-81a5-4b2d-9d08-21baf10134bd",
      "cacheExpireDate": "10/31/2018 1:45:55 AM"
    },
    "stats": [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "key": "level",
          "name": "Level",
          "categoryKey": "levels",
          "categoryName": "Levels",
          "isReversed": false,
          "iconUrl": "https://cod-cdn.tracker.gg/assets/ranks/rank_6.png"
        },
        "value": 6.0,
        "percentile": 92.0,
        "displayValue": "6"
      },
      {
        "metadata": {
          "key": "KDRatio",
          "name": "KD Ratio",
          "categoryKey": "combat",
          "categoryName": "Combat",
          "isReversed": false
        },
        "value": 0.39,
        "percentile": 96.0,
        "displayValue": "0.39",
        "displayRank": ""
      },
```

I am trying to get the values for both the Level & KD Ratio and be placed on a label.

However, I get an error "keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "stats", intValue: nil)

Here is my current code. Any help would be great.

```
struct Data: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let type: String?
    let stats: [Stats]
}

struct Stats: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let categoryName: String?
    let displayValue: Int?
    let value: Int?
}

class StatTrackerVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var accountNameLabel: UILabel!

    let blackOps4TrackerNetworkAPI = "4db06ff7-4499-494d-8d75-93a9b38292a3"
    let urlString = URL(string: "https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/1/BarMexico67")


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/1/BarMexico67"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
            { return }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue(blackOps4TrackerNetworkAPI, forHTTPHeaderField: "TRN-Api-Key")


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
            //Perhaps Check Err
            //Check Response Status 200 OK

            guard let data = data else { return }

//            let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
//            print(dataAsString!)

            do {
                let stats = try JSONDecoder().decode(Data.self, from: data)
                print(stats)

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error Serializing JSON:", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `stats` object is not inside the `data` object rather they are on the same level. So, `stats` array should not be inside the `Data` type. Also inside stat objects, `metaData` is a child object with keys like `key`, `categoryKey`, `categoryName` etc while `value`, `percentile` and `displayValue` are part of the `stat` object. The correct implementation of the decodable types is as below,

```
struct TrackerResponse: Decodable {
     let data: StatData?
     let stats: [Stat]?
}

struct StatData: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let type: String?
    let accountId: String?
    let platformId: Int?
}


struct Stat: Decodable {
    let value: Int?
    let metadata: StatMeta?
    let percentile: Int?
    let displayValue: String?
}

struct StatMeta: Decodable {
    let key: String?
    let name: String?
    let categoryKey: String?
    let categoryName: String?
}
```

So, now you should `decode` `TrackerResponse`, as below,

```
do {
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(TrackerResponse.self, from: data)
    print(response.data?.id)

} catch let jsonErr {
    print("Error Serializing JSON:", jsonErr)
}
```

Comment: You aren't handling everything. And what's up with all those optionals?

Comment: Didn't get handling everything? All `Optionals` is because i don't know the backend, its up to the OP to decide what members can be `optionals` or `non-optionals`. The example is guaranteed to give crash free code.

Comment: Fix your keys and I'll take back my downvote. You are missing keys.

Comment: I believe, we provide solution to a problem here on SO rather than complete implementation that even OP is not bothered about. Voting up or down are personal choices and i am ok as far as OP's issue is fixed.

Comment: This works and allows me to see both the id and type. My second thing is how am I able to get the display values from "Stat". Everytime I am geting that the display value is nil.

Comment: @user3667192 It is because the stats object is `nil` in the response. You need to ask the backend for that. Or you might have to try with a profile that has stats in it.

Comment: @user3667192 I added a `print` statement  in answer to log the `data`  returned from the API response. Now you should be able to see what your server is sending for that particular request.

Comment: Thank you for your help.